# Clients seem to be running old (buggy) code after XPO project import

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009, aot

I have imported an XPO project file into our production AOS server, the code is visually the right one (if I open the related methods included in this XPO) but yet, it seems old code is executed.

After importing the XPO, I had all AOS services of all our AOS servers restarted, all clients were disconnected so I can't think of them running cached code somehow.

I did the same when moving the code from DEV to TEST to STAGING with no problem.

Anything I'm missing you think ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have found this can be caused by code executing from the client cache instead of the server. Run a `del /s *.auc` from the command prompt of the user having issues after shutting down AX. It has fixed the problem for us in the past. We have also added this to our domain group policy to run for every user on startup, so we can just tell users to restart their computer if they're having issues.

Comment: Do you have the precise path where this file could be found ?

Comment: Nevermind, found it: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local - Thanks. I'll try this and flag as answer if it does solve my issue

Comment: Normally when you open the command prompt, it starts at the user's root profile folder, which is why I didn't include it. I don't know of any other program that would use a .auc file, so we just blanket delete all of them to be safe.